# Apache/2.2.22 You don't have permission to access / on this server error

Tags: apache-httpd

I tried all suggestions about permissions I could find but without luck. Apache seems to start normally

```
[ ok ] Restarting web server: apache2 ... waiting ..
```

Access log says

```
192.168.15.51 - - [12/Feb/2016:04:19:48 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 498 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"
```

Error log:

```
[Fri Feb 12 04:19:48 2016] [error] [client 192.168.15.51] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

ls -al /var/www:

```
root@AOScloud:/etc/apache2# ls -la /var/www
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Feb 12 03:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root     root     4096 Feb 12 03:31 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  177 Feb 12 03:33 index.html
```

ls -ld /var/www

```
root@AOScloud:/etc/apache2# ls -ld /var/www
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 12 03:33 /var/www
```

In apache2.conf I added

```
DocumentRoot /var/www

<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I am running a Debian 4.2.0 Kernel

This is the content of /etc/apache2/sites-available/default as requested below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: if you're using apache 2.2, first thing, the directive `Require all granted` should be replace by: `Order allow,deny\nAllow from all`

Comment: Changed but no change in result...

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -la /var/www`

Comment: Did you restart Apache after changing the config file?

Comment: Yes I did. Output of ls added.

Comment: Can you also include `ls -ld /var/www`

Comment: you are missing `DocumentRoot /var/www` and then restart (outside of the Directory directive)

Comment: Added, still no access...

Comment: Can you please share de content inside `<Directory /var/www/></Directory>` of your virtual host, I might it is in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

Comment: Added above....

Comment: Anything in your syslog/messages? What OS are you using?

Comment: Debian 4.2.0 Kernel, I cannot find a syslog in /var/log/

Comment: Anything of interest in this log file: "/var/log/messages" ?

Comment: Have you tried taking out from `apache2.conf` the `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` stuff and only leave the `default's`?

Comment: @kph0x1: I do not have this file.

Comment: You **have** to have a syslog or messages log. Debian is /var/log/messages, I believe.

Comment: @Reto Ok I'll post it as an answer, if it doesn't help I'll delete it.

Comment: I tried starting from blank: `apt-get remove --purge apache2` and then `apt-get install apache2`. I receive an error `Unpacking apache2 (from .../apache2_2.2.22-13+deb7u6_armel.deb) ...
Setting up apache2 (2.2.22-13+deb7u6) ...
Error connecting: Exhausted all available authentication mechanisms (tried: EXTERNAL, DBUS_COOKIE_SHA1, ANONYMOUS) (available: EXTERNAL, DBUS_COOKIE_SHA1, ANONYMOUS)` In a browser I still get `Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now. For some reason www-data user was corrupt... I added a new user www and changed everything to this user www. Now it works...

Answer (score 0):

Apache from a Debian based package defaults for review below:

https://catjcode.com/apache_conf.txt "Default apache conf"

https://catjcode.com/apache_site.txt "Default apache site"

Try a more minimal, default configuration for getting the http://192.168.15.1/index.html or similar accessible. Then and add back in each needed portion of your configuration.

Another possible issue in the log message posted:

```
access to / denied
```

Server could be configured in a way such that attempting to view, `http://192.168.15.1/` was seen as an index: Apache directory indexes or file listing, which are often turned off by default. The default handler as `index.html` could be lacking configuration. Suggest attempt directly going to `http://192.168.15.1/index.html` to see if error in log is different.

Also check symbolic links if any. Suppose your site is actually not using `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` as its configuration, there being a different file in use, negating any of your changes. below from typical setup; note symbolic link and naming scheme:

```
ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ -lah
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Aug 29 11:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4.0K Aug 29 11:40 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Aug 29 11:38 000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
```

To help diagnose permission issues: check if www-data is used by Apache, start Apache and then review the process owner. Note www-data below:

```
ps -ef|fgrep apache

root      1495     1  0 Feb16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  5239  1495  0 09:33 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  5240  1495  0 09:33 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Review file system permissions; example below:

```
ls -lah /var/www/html/
drwxr-xr-x 6 root     root 4.0K Sep  9 13:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root 4.0K Aug 29 11:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data root 4.0K Aug 30 17:56 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data root 4.0K Sep  9 13:26 css
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data root 4.0K Sep  8 12:36 images
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data root 4.0K Sep  9 10:14 js
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root 3.4K Sep  9 13:14 index.html
```

Comment: You mean I should replace my apache2.conf with the content of apache_conf.txt? And where should apache_site.txt go?

Comment: Replace or review and locate anything varying from defaults. The site would be in your case /etc/apache2/sites-available/default. Be sure any sym link is OK when changing, moving around the site file.

Comment: I am still on default. Nothing changed since I installed apache. index.html still contains the default apache code.

Comment: I used your `apache conf` and `apache site`. With `apache site` there was an error when starting the server `/var/www/html does not exist`. So I created it and added index.html. Still the same error, even with IP/index.html: `You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.` With your `apache conf` I get an error `Invalid command 'Mutex'`

Comment: How can I check if apache really uses www-data user? It looks like www-data is set as user in the config file, but how can I double check?